# Magento 2 how to show catalog/product/list.phtml in Custom Module collection

Tags: magento2, catalog, product-list

Magento 2 how to show catalog/product/list.phtml in Custom Module popup with custom filter product collection
Anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList.php and overwrite _getProductCollection() class in Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

```
protected function _getProductCollection()

  /*your code here*/  

    $this->_productCollection = $yourcollection;
    return $this->_productCollection;
```

Now, the collection has been moved to your phtml file

```
$block = $viewBlock->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList')
                ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
                ->toHtml();"
```

Comment: can we get filter collection using this ?

Comment: No. By doing the above, you will receive all products in the store. To be able to receive products by a filter you can see how in our example below.


For initial use you need to declare the following classes in your __construct:
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper

Comment: public function _getProductCollection() {
        / get all category ids of current store /
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $currentStoreAllCategories = $this->categoryHelper->getStoreCategories(false,true,true);

Comment: $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','sku'));
        // filter current website products
        $collection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteId);
        // set visibility filter
        $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

        /*SKU Filter Here*/
        $sku = array('24-MB04', '24-MB03', '24-MB02');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $sku));

Comment: //You can return items or data or whatever you want in this collection
        return $collection->getItem();
    }

Comment: In this example we are filtering by product's sku, you can completely change it according to your own filters, then you can get the full product according to your filter.